# aws - how to create email address for my domain hosted in Route53?

Tags: amazon-route53, amazon-ses

I have http://awsclub.org registered through Route53

[image]

### How do I create email accounts and then read their mail?

#### Not sure if it's Route53 or SES where I need to set this.

#### In SES I have:

[image: aws]

but of course I can't verify that until I have an email account with username/password

For email client setup, I need paasword

[image]

In Route53 I have:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

SES doesn't provide mailboxes which means it doesn't provide POP/IMAP services, you have MX record pointed to inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com , you can use SES recipient rule and save the email to S3 and download it from S3 and change the file extension to .eml and open it in mail client and verify the email.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html

To receive/send email, the domain needs to be verified, you can verify your domain instead which will allow you to use any email address in your domain.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html

However, if you would like to receive an email in mailbox, you need to use Workmail provided by AWS.